# Question On Stack Permutation

Tags: algorithm

I want to ask that is it necessary that first number in stack permutation should be 1 and last should be n(last number in queue). The examples on web I have seen all have first element 1 and last as n. But using stack permutation algo we can get any number on first place and any on last place.

Comment: Could you give more background/information here? What examples have you seen, and to what do they relate?

Comment: related: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Stack+Permutation+problem%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permuting a stack should give you a stack which is isomorphic to the original and so the starting state is mostly irrelevant and you could just relabel it as { 1, 2, 3 ... n } so yes, you could start at any number and end at any other.

The web has it from 1 through N because that makes it easier to explain.